# Delete all product images from a specific category?

Tags: image

I recently uploaded some images for products and accidently duplicated them for products that are all listed within a specific category.

I've looked around and [found a solution](http://www.hummingbirduk.com/batch-remove-images-from-products-in-magento/) that claims to **delete all** images, but I want to do this for a specific category (category ID).

I can't be the first to have had this happen.

**How can I delete all product images (only the images) from a specific category?**

Comment: Just filter your collection with category id and use solution you have found in blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the script you provided as solution, you only need to filter the product collection by category id

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');

$categoryId = 3; // set your category ID here

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('eq' => $categoryId));

$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");

foreach(array_keys($products->getItems()) as $productId) {
    $items = $mediaApi->items($productId);
    if (count($items) > 0) { 
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $mediaApi->remove($productId, $item['file']);
        }
        echo $productId . " done \n";
    } else { 
        echo $productId . " has no images \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, it works a little slowly but does the job. Thank you. SR